# AngularJS polyfill/alternative for Object.assign

Tags: javascript, angularjs

### Failed to instantiate module due to : TypeError: object doesn't support property or method 'assign' at setConfig

I'm trying to run an angular app on IE11. And there is a piece of code in details.js file which is throwing an error.

```
this.setConfig = (config) => {
    if (config) {
        Object.assign(detailsConfig, config);  
    }
};
```

Error in the console of IE11 is as below.

> [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module detailsPortal due to:
>       TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'assign'
>       at setConfig()

Because of this error, my angular app is not loading on IE11, it is displaying a blank screen.

Comment: ie 11 doesn't support object assign: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign perhaps a polyfill would help.

Comment: @DanielA.White Isn't Angular supposed to provide polyfills? But my company also runs into some cases where Angular isn't polyfilling as expected.

Comment: i dont think it would.

Comment: AngularJS provides [angular.extend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend) which copies enumerated properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `Object.assign`, use `angular.extend`:

```
this.setConfig = (config) => {
    if (config) {
        ̶O̶b̶j̶e̶c̶t̶.̶a̶s̶s̶i̶g̶n̶(̶d̶e̶t̶a̶i̶l̶s̶C̶o̶n̶f̶i̶g̶,̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶f̶i̶g̶)̶;̶ ̶
        angular.extend(detailsConfig, config);  
    }
};
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS angular.extend Function API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend)